# Execute c shell commands with variables

Tags: unix, command-line-arguments, csh

How do I pass variables as parameters to commands in a c shell?

Something like this:

```
    vncserver -depth $BITDEPTH -geometry $WIDTHx$HEIGHT
```

I appreciate your help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The bit that might be causing confusion is the geometry: you're passing the concatenation of variable `${WIDTHx}` and `${HEIGHT}` (which was not what you had in mind).

Try:

```
vncserver -depth ${BITDEPTH} -geometry ${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}
```

The only mandatory braces are those around `${WIDTH}` (though the local coding standards here say 'all variable expansions shall use braces around the name', but they also say 'thou shalt not use C shell for scripting'); the others are for uniformity.